# 2 Way Encryption Algorithm that for both Ruby & Node.JS that only encrypts to letters and numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, encryption, aes

I have a node.js server that will encrypt a string and store it into a database. I also have a RoR(Ruby on Rails) server that will retrieve the encrypted string from the database and decrypt it. The only criteria I have is that the encryption must only encrypt strings into a string of letters and numbers (no special characters)

Any suggestions

Comment: Encryption produces bytes, not strings. You can represent arbitrary bytes using [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which eliminates most "special characters" in the resultant string.

Comment: @MattBall You should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @MattBall can you suggest an encryption library available for both node and ruby that will help me accomplish my task?

Comment: Sorry, no idea - I don't do Ruby. Try a Blowfish implementation.

Comment: AES (With appropriate chaining mode and IV) together with Base64 should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, a strong encryption like AES-CBC or AES-CTR together with Base-64 is one solution.  Base-64 uses +, / and = in addition to the 62 alphanumeric characters.  Hex (Base-16) is strictly alphanumeric, but takes more storage space.  Base-32 only has the padding character, =, like Base-64.  In a pinch it is possible to omit padding, and to recalculate in for decoding.

If you are wiling to accept a lower level of security then one alternative is to use a [Vigenère cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenere_cipher), where you can explicitly determine the input and output characters allowed.